# How to assign hotkeys to navigate folders only when Windows Explorer is active?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to using numbers to quickly navigate some frequent folders **only when Windows Explorer is active**; the use of those keys in other programs is unchanged. [This thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/102127-navigating-explorer-directories/?p=634365) provides the code matches my need, except it will use `Run` if no Explorer window is active, which I've stripped out in the code below:

```
#e::Run Explorer D:\Download
1::NavRun("D:\Download")
3::NavRun("E:\Setups")
4::NavRun("E:\Music")
8::NavRun("D:\")
9::NavRun("E:\")
0::NavRun("F:\")

; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094
GetActiveExplorer() {
    static objShell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    WinHWND := WinActive("A")    ; Active window
    for Item in objShell.Windows
        if (Item.HWND = WinHWND)
            return Item        ; Return active window object
    return -1    ; No explorer windows match active window
}

NavRun(Path) {
    if (-1 != objIE := GetActiveExplorer())
        objIE.Navigate(Path)
}
```

However, I cannot use the numbers listed in the script anymore in any other programs. How can they be used again?

Comment: Use the [#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive to make your hotkeys context-sensitive. Replace "`#IfWinActive [, WinTitle, WinText]`" with "`#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass`" (CabinetWClass is the window class of the Windows Explorer) and add "`#IfWinActive`" to turn off the context sensitivity.

Comment: It works, except that the hotkeys in Explorer don't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Hold the key pressed for longer than 0.3 seconds in explorer to navigate to a directory.

```
#UseHook

#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass") ; explorer

    1::
    2::
    3::
    4::
    KeyWait, %A_ThisHotkey%, T0.3
    if (ErrorLevel)
        long_press := true
    else
        Send, %A_ThisHotkey%
    return

#If (long_press)

    1 Up::
    2 Up::
    3 Up::
    4 Up::
    long_press := false
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "1")
        NavRun("C:\")
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "2")
        NavRun("D:\")
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "3")
        NavRun("E:\")
    return

#If

; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094
GetActiveExplorer() {
    static objShell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    WinHWND := WinActive("A")    ; Active window
    for Item in objShell.Windows
        if (Item.HWND = WinHWND)
            return Item        ; Return active window object
    return -1    ; No explorer windows match active window
}

NavRun(Path) {
    if (-1 != objIE := GetActiveExplorer())
        objIE.Navigate(Path)
    else
        Run, % Path
}
```

This way you can use the keys in a normal way if you want to type text in explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I make it to 0.1 to make the press more natural. So far so good for me.